# How to put DB in Sandboxed area in iOS App and access the path?

Tags: ios, database, sandbox

now, I have DB Data being used on Linux and Window.

I'd like to put it in the iPhone, and use them in my iOS Application.

How to put DB in Sandbox area of ​​my iOS Application ?? And where is the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you’d use `FileManager` method `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` to build a file URL:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")
```

So, if you had a blank database in your bundle, you’d copy that initial copy of the database to the above file URL, and then open it using this URL from that point on. Or if you were programmatically creating the database from scratch, you’d again use this resulting file `URL`.

But don’t save this absolute path anywhere. Always build it programmatically like above.

---

Note, historically we used to use the `.documentsDirectory` for things like this (and you’ll see lots of those sorts of answers lingering about on the web). But nowadays we would use the `.applicationSupportDirectory`. See [iOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW13) document or the [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/) video.

Comment: Can't I put my DB in that path after the app is installed ?. (My DB is huge, at least 10GB).

According to your answer, I understood that my DB must be included in the App Bundle.

Comment: Yep, you can put it there whenever you want. I was just trying to outline common scenarios (some people create databases on the fly; some ship them with their app).

Comment: @Wls As an aside, a 10 gb database starts to make me wonder if you really want this on device. When dealing with that sort of volume, one would often put it in the cloud and write a web service that devices could call to retrieve the necessary data. Perhaps you really need offline access and have no data sharing needs, in which case, you have to do what you have to do, but just sayin’...

Comment: Actually, My Database is NDS Map Data. I'm creating Navigation System in iOS Env. I have found that I can put files in the Document area of ​​the App through iTunes or Finder. But I had another problem. Could you answer the question below link?
https://url.kr/uypY7D